# Java JComboBox Placeholder

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, placeholder

**good day**

Currently I am developing a desktop application in java with GUI NetBeans, every time I realize that using it is somewhat counterproductive, I am something new in this, my application has a form in which there are several combobox, in which I want to achieve a placeholder effect.

Example of what I would like to achieve:

```
*Country
Germany
Brazil
Japan
United States
```

I would like the word "country" to appear in the combobox but not be selectable and thus achieve the placeholder effect, but I have no idea how to do that.

At the moment what I have is the title "country" in the index 0 of the combobox, which I do not like at all that it is a selectable option, at the moment I start the combobox with a `cmbo_country.setForeground(Color.gray);` to simulate the placeholder effect.

Then when the selection of the combobox changes the index 0 "country" to any other change the color to white and delete the index 0.

```
cmbo_country.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
cmbo_country.removeItemAt(0);
```

but this is a very bad solution.

can you help me with this?

As I was reading I saw the possibility of using a negative index (-1) which I can select by default and not show it in the selection, but I can't do this since I immediately get an error.

`cmbo_country.insertItemAt("Country", -1);`

Error: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

which I have not gotten any way to increase the limits so that the index (-1) is allowed, I do not know if this is the best solution but I appreciate the help you can give me.

Thanks in advance.

**Upgrade**

Testing the class: `PromptComboBoxRenderer`

As I said I am working with the netbeans GUI

```
public class Jframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Jframe() {
        initComponents();
        
        setTitle("CMBO Prueba");
        setSize(600,400);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        jComboBox1.removeAllItems();        
        jComboBox1.addItem("Germany");
        jComboBox1.addItem("Brazil");
        jComboBox1.addItem("Japan");
        jComboBox1.addItem("United States");
        
    }
.
.
.

}
```

So far I have my standard combobox:

[sample][1]

[shows combobox open][2]

Now applying the class `PromptComboBoxRenderer`

```java
public class Jframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    public Jframe() {
        initComponents();
        
        setTitle("CMBO Prueba");
        setSize(600,400);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        jComboBox1.removeAllItems();        
        jComboBox1.addItem("Germany");
        jComboBox1.addItem("Brazil");
        jComboBox1.addItem("Japan");
        jComboBox1.addItem("United States");
        
        jComboBox1.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        
        jComboBox1.setRenderer(new PromptComboBoxRenderer("Country"));

    }
.
.
.

}
```

So far the result seems correct

[classy sample applied][3]

the problem occurs when opening the combobox it has completely lost its color, something similar to the function `jComboBox1.setEnabled(false);` also the color of the selection is lost.

[selection sample without color][4]

I have tried applying the selection color myself in the following way:

```java
public class Jframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    /**
     * Creates new form Jframe
     */
    public Jframe() {
        initComponents();
        
        setTitle("CMBO Prueba");
        setSize(600,400);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        jComboBox1.removeAllItems();        
        jComboBox1.addItem("Germany");
        jComboBox1.addItem("Brazil");
        jComboBox1.addItem("Japan");
        jComboBox1.addItem("United States");
        
        jComboBox1.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        
        jComboBox1.setRenderer(new PromptComboBoxRenderer("Country"));
     
 
        jComboBox1.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
        public void paintCurrentValueBackground(Graphics g,
                                Rectangle bounds,
                                boolean hasFocus)
     {
         g.setColor( Color.RED );            
         g.fillRect(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
     }
});
    
    }
.
.
.
}
```

this didn't work for me either, firstly the placeholder effect is lost and the combobox is blank

[sample][5]

also although now if I obtain the selection it is not painted in the color of the example, in this case red.

[selection swatch with color][6]

Thanks in advance for all the help you can offer me and sorry for the newbie.

**Add**

I have incorporated the following function to change the L&F and see what I got:

```
public void ChangeFormat(){
    
        try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Jframe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
    
    }
```

here the result, now the problem is not in the selection but in the combobox with a white cap.

[shows when changing the L&F][7]

when you open it everything seems correct

[sample][8]

although I would not like to change the L&F of nimbus for my project maybe this will help to find a solution

thanks for the help you can give me.

**new update**

applying the new thing, try to modify the extends I have put `SynthComboBoxRenderer` but that does not work for me because I think it is not right with the components, this is what I get with the`.getRenderer()`:

```
javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthComboBoxUI$SynthComboBoxRenderer[ComboBox.listRenderer,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@16514247,flags=8388616,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=Item 4,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
```

can I apply it in the class `PromptComboBoxRenderer` ??? Thank you very much for all the help

**next update**

I have tested the original code of the class `PromptComboBoxRenderer` in a blank project and I have verified that it works without problems:

```java
package class;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class test {
    
    private JComboBox combo;
    
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
       
    }
     
     public test(){
     
        JFrame v=new JFrame("window);
        combo = new JComboBox();
        combo.addItem("Germany");
        combo.addItem("Brazil");
        combo.addItem("Japan");
        combo.addItem("United States");
        
        v.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
        v.pack();
        v.getContentPane().add(combo);
        v.setVisible(true);
        v.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        v.add(new Panel());
        v.setSize(600, 400);
        v.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        combo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        
        combo.setRenderer(new PromptComboBoxRenderer("Country"));

     }
     
    
}
```

the problem occurs as I have seen when using the jframe creator and using the Nimbus UI.

This being the case that I need to be able to apply to my project, I leave the complete code and the problem in question until the moment of what has been achieved.

```java
package ventanas;

import clases.PromptComboBoxRenderer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Jframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Jframe() {
 
        initComponents();
        
        setTitle("CMBO Prueba");
        setSize(600,400);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
        
        jComboBox1.addItem("Germany");
    jComboBox1.addItem("Brazil");
    jComboBox1.addItem("Japan");
        jComboBox1.addItem("United States");
        
        jComboBox1.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        
        jComboBox1.setRenderer(new PromptComboBoxRenderer("Country"));
        
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
        getContentPane().add(jComboBox1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(150, 60, 260, 40));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Jframe().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

As I have said before, this way is the closest I have managed to solve the problem since the desired effect is applied successfully, the only problem is that the selection color is lost when the mouse passes through the different options of the combobox by For some reason and I can't give it back that selection color either. It seems that when opening the combobox the selections have a method`jComboBox1.setEnabled(false);`.

I have already left a picture of that above

the other way that I tried and without getting any results was:

```java
package ventanas;

import clases.PromptComboBoxRenderer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Jframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Jframe() {
 
        initComponents();
        
        setTitle("CMBO Prueba");
        setSize(600,400);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
        
        jComboBox1.addItem("Germany");
    jComboBox1.addItem("Brazil");
    jComboBox1.addItem("Japan");
        jComboBox1.addItem("United States");
        
        jComboBox1.setSelectedIndex(-1);

        jComboBox1 = new JComboBox<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public Object getSelectedItem()
            {
                Object selected = super.getSelectedItem();

                if (selected == null)
                    selected = "Country";

                return selected;
            }
        };

        
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
        getContentPane().add(jComboBox1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(150, 60, 260, 40));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Jframe().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I hope you can help me solve this, thanks in advance

Comment: One option would be to put "Country" in a JLabel next to or above the JComboBox.

Comment: 1) That is not an [mre], since I can't copy/paste/compile and test. 2) As I suggested you are not using the default LAF and therefore the renderer used by your code is NOT the BasicComboBoxRenderer. So instead of extending BasicComboBoxRenderer you should extend the default renderer used by your LAF. You just use the `getRenderer()` method of the combo box to get the default renderer. Then you should be able to add the basic logic found in my renderer.

Comment: @camickr Again thanks for all your help, sorry not to put a complete executable code but this is created automatically with GUI netbeans, I will consider soon creating a Jframe from the beginning with code, I still do not solve the problem but the above makes a lot of sense, no I understand how to modify the extends, I have updated in the question what I am trying, I hope you can help me friend, thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: *javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthComboBoxUI$SynthComboBoxRenderer* - so the default renderer of Nimbus is an internal class. Therefore is can't be extended since it will use instance variable of the SynthComboBoxUI class that we don't have access to. So the approach suggested here will not work for the Nimbus LAF.

Comment: @camickr I understand, is there any way to achieve that effect (placeholder) with nimbus L&F or can you give me one last advice on how to apply it if I publish the code of my custom Combobox which I am working with BasicComboBoxUI ??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ramej May have an alternative approach. Not sure if it works on Nimbus or not.

Comment: @ramej, well, did the alternative approach work?

Comment: @camickr Good friend, thank you very much for your help, sorry but I was away for a few days. I have added an update to the post to see if you can give me a hand, thank you very much

Comment: I gave you an alternative approach. If it doesn't help, I have no more suggestions.

Comment: @camickr ok friend thank you very much for all your help

Answer (score 1):

> I would like the word "country" to appear in the combobox but not be selectable and thus achieve the placeholder effect

You can use a custom renderer for the combo box to achieve this effect:

```
class PromptComboBoxRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer
{
    private String prompt;

    /*
     *  Set the text to display when no item has been selected.
     */
    public PromptComboBoxRenderer(String prompt)
    {
        this.prompt = prompt;
    }

    /*
     *  Custom rendering to display the prompt text when no item is selected
     */
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        if (value == null)
            setText( prompt );

        return this;
    }
}
```

The renderer will display your prompt when no value is selected.

When the combo box is created the first item in the combo box is selected so you will need to clear the selection by using:

```
comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
```

See [Combo Box Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/18/combo-box-prompt/) for full information.

### Alternative approach:

Some Look and Feels, like Nimbus, don't use the `BasicComboBoxRenderer` so it may be more difficult to extend the default renderer to display the prompt text.

In this case you might be able to override the `getSelectedItem()` method to achieve the same effect:

```
comboBox = new JComboBox<String>( ... )
{
    @Override
    public Object getSelectedItem()
    {
        Object selected = super.getSelectedItem();

        if (selected == null)
            selected = "Country";

        return selected;
    }
};
```